# Where to ask for a software suggestion?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I'm wondering: what is the right place to ask for a suggestion for some software with desired functionality? (When the first choice - Google doesn't provide a sufficient answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a dedicated site for this in the network, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Before posting your question there, please have a look at their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377) to increase the chance of a good solution to your needs.